# Integrating Accelerated Mobile Pages(AMP) into existing backbone application

Tags: backbone.js, single-page-application, amp-html

I've a Backbone application, which initialises from index.html. I tried adding new amp html called index.amp.html and followed instructions in [Create Your AMP HTML Page](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/get_started/create_page.html).

My index.html has only hook to require js to start loading backbone app. All the html is generated dynamically.

Is there a way I can include AMP practices in dynamic generated HTML? Because all I have is one index.html entire content is generated through handlebars dynamically on client side.

I didn't find any good article to make SPAs to support AMP. Are there any best practices to follow? Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

At this time, the only JavaScripts that can be triggered in an AMP document are these two scripts:

```
<script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script>
<script async custom-element="amp-analytics" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-analytics-0.1.js"></script>
```

You can use a mustache template as part of the custom-element script as follows:

```
<script async custom-template="amp-mustache" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mustache-0.1.js"></script>
```

The templates are described here:
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-html-templates.md

Without access to your code, can't say how easy or difficult it may be to modify your handlebar templates to fit the model above.